# Cast and merge two lists of same interfaces but different types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface, casting

I got two entities with using same interface. I want to merge both results I get from entity framework to one list of `IKurs`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IKurs<ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData>, IAdditionalTeacherData>>> GetCourses(bool takeXtr)
{
    IEnumerable<IKurs<ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData>, IAdditionalTeacherData>> result  = new List<IKurs<ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData>, IAdditionalTeacherData>>();
    if (takeXtr)
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var courses = context.XtrCourses.Include(x=>x.TeachersToCourses).Where(_someCourseFilterForAgs);
            result.Concat(await courses.ToListAsync()).Cast<IKurs<ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData>, IAdditionalTeacherData>>();
        }

    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        var courses = context.AgsCourses.Include(x=>x.TeachersToCourses).Where(_someCourseFilterForAgs);
        result.Concat(await courses.ToListAsync()).Cast<IKurs<ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData>, IAdditionalTeacherData>>();
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, I tried casting them both with 
`.Cast<IKurs<ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData>, IAdditionalTeacherData>>()` (that throws an InvalidCastException)

These are my `Course` classes, both implementing `IKurs<T1<T2>, T1>` but their T1 and T2 are different (but still they use the same interfaces):

```
public class XtrCourse : Core_Xtr_Course, IKurs<XtrTeacherToCourse, XtrAdditionalTeacherData>
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    // properties

    public ICollection<XtrTeacherToCourse> TeachersToCourses { get; set; }
}

public class AgsCourse : Core_Ags_Course, IKurs<AgsTeacherToCourse, AgsAdditionalTeacherData>
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    // properties

    public ICollection<AgsTeacherToCourse> TeachersToCourses { get; set; }
}

public interface IKurs<TTeacherToCourse, TAdditionalTeacherData>
        where TTeacherToCourse : ITeacherToCourse<TAdditionalTeacherData>
        where TAdditionalTeacherData: IAdditionalTeacherData
{
    int Nr { get; set; }

    ICollection<TTeacherToCourse> TeachersToCourses { get; set; }
}

public interface ITeacherToCourse<T> where T : IAdditionalTeacherData
{
    int Nr { get; set; }
    T AdditionalTeacherData { get; set; }
}

public interface IAdditionalTeacherData
{
    // properties
}
```

classes `AgsTeacherToCourse` and `XtrTeacherToCourse` both implement `ITeacherToCourse`
classes `AgsTeacherToCourse` and `XtrTeacherToCourse` both implement `ITeacherToCourse`

How can I merge them to one list?

In real, both course-lists come from different contexts. That's why I'm initiating the context in `GetCourses()` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main problems is

```
interface ITeacherToCourse<T> where T : IAdditionalTeacherData
{
    int Nr { get; set; }
    T AdditionalTeacherData { get; set; }
}

class XtrTeacherToCourse : ITeacherToCourse<XtrAdditionalTeacherData>
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public XtrAdditionalTeacherData AdditionalTeacherData { get; set; }
}

class AgsTeacherToCourse : ITeacherToCourse<AgsAdditionalTeacherData>
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public AgsAdditionalTeacherData AdditionalTeacherData { get; set; }
}
```

The interface contract defines that you can only **set** a value to `AdditionalTeacherData` of type `XtrAdditionalTeacherData` for `XtrAdditionalTeacherData` and `AgsAdditionalTeacherData` for `AgsTeacherToCourse`.

How can we ensure this contract when we were able to

```
ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData> ttc = new XtrTeacherToCourse();
ttc.AdditionalTeacherData = new AgsAdditionalTeacherData();
```

If you do not want to **set** the `AdditionalTeacherData` property then you can declare the interface like

```
interface ITeacherToCourse<out T> where T : IAdditionalTeacherData
{
    int Nr { get; set; }
    T AdditionalTeacherData { get; }
}
```

`AdditionalTeacherData` is now **readonly** and `T` is an `out T`.

Now we are able to

```
ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData> ttc; 
ttc = new XtrTeacherToCourse();
ttc = new AgsTeacherToCourse();
```

With the collections it is the same.

The total interface declaration

```
interface IAdditionalTeacherData
{

}

interface ITeacherToCourse<out T> where T : IAdditionalTeacherData
{
    int Nr { get; set; }
    T AdditionalTeacherData { get; }
}

interface IKurs<out TTeacherToCourse, out TAdditionalTeacherData>
    where TTeacherToCourse : ITeacherToCourse<TAdditionalTeacherData>
    where TAdditionalTeacherData : IAdditionalTeacherData
{
    int Nr { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<TTeacherToCourse> TeachersToCourses { get; }
}
```

and the implementing classes

```
class XtrAdditionalTeacherData : IAdditionalTeacherData
{

}

class XtrTeacherToCourse : ITeacherToCourse<XtrAdditionalTeacherData>
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public XtrAdditionalTeacherData AdditionalTeacherData { get; set; }
}

class XtrCourse : IKurs<XtrTeacherToCourse, XtrAdditionalTeacherData>
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public ICollection<XtrTeacherToCourse> TeachersToCourses { get; set; }
    // explicit implementation
    IEnumerable<XtrTeacherToCourse> IKurs<XtrTeacherToCourse, XtrAdditionalTeacherData>.TeachersToCourses => TeachersToCourses;
}

class AgsAdditionalTeacherData : IAdditionalTeacherData
{

}

class AgsTeacherToCourse : ITeacherToCourse<AgsAdditionalTeacherData>
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public AgsAdditionalTeacherData AdditionalTeacherData { get; set; }
}

class AgsCourse : IKurs<AgsTeacherToCourse, AgsAdditionalTeacherData>
{
    public int Nr { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AgsTeacherToCourse> TeachersToCourses { get; set; }
    // explicit implementation
    IEnumerable<AgsTeacherToCourse> IKurs<AgsTeacherToCourse, AgsAdditionalTeacherData>.TeachersToCourses => TeachersToCourses;
}
```

and now we can add the instances without any cast

```
var collection = new List<IKurs<ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData>, IAdditionalTeacherData>>();

collection.Add(new XtrCourse());
collection.Add(new AgsCourse());
```

Comment: Wow. Perfect. The `out` was exactly the problem. Thx for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Casting is not necessary, you can add any `IKurs<ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData>, IAdditionalTeacherData>` to your list.

```
    interface IMyclass{}

    class MyType1 : IMyclass {}

    class MyType2 : IMyclass {}

    public class SomeClass
    {
        private List<IMyclass> MyList = new List<IMyclass>();

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            MyList.AddRange(new List<IMyclass> { new MyType1(), new MyType1() });
            MyList.AddRange(new List<IMyclass> { new MyType2(), new MyType2() });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried with `result.AddRange(await courses.ToListAsync());` but this makes my compiler crying :( `Argument type List<AgsCourse> is not assignable to parametertype IEnumerable<IKurs<ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData>, IAdditionalTeacherData>>` - I think I'd first need to cast the complete structure then?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger something must be up with your types. I have to admit I am getting confused with your complicated type definitions, but as long as you get this error form your compiler, casting will not work. The error basically tells you that casting will not work.

Comment: I still don't exactly know why, but Sir Rufo has spotted the problem. I need to research why I need to use `out` in my interface here. But thx for your help :) - And yes, the structure is confusing. You're right - It's not my database-design :D