# Code-Design good practice bad practice of interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, interface

In relation to my question: 
[Cast and merge two lists of same interfaces but different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583461/cast-and-merge-two-lists-of-same-interfaces-but-different-types)

I had a generic interface-definition of

```
IKurs<ITeacherToCourse<IAdditionalTeacherData>, IAdditionalTeacherData>
```

**Why:**

There are two databases sharing nearly an identical database-schema
What I'm trying to do is, with using of 2 database-contexts a union of datasets.

```
// a bit a kind of pseudo-code

List<**GenericInterface**> unionlist = new List<**GenericInterface**>();

using (var context1 = new FirstContext())
{
    unionlist.AddRange(await context1.Courses.ToListAsync());
}
using (var context2 = new SecondContext())
{
    unionlist.AddRange(await context2.Courses.ToListAsync());    
}
return unionlist;
```

all tables in both databases are classes sharing the same interfaces. There are a lot of references from `Course`-class so my interface now is s.th like this:

```
public interface IKurs<out T, out TDozent, out TKursInformation, out TKurseStichwoerter, out TStichwort> : IKurs
    where T : ILehrerZuKurs<TDozent>
    where TDozent : IZusatzDozent
    where TKursInformation : IKursInformation
    where TKurseStichwoerter : IKurseStichwoerter<TStichwort>
    where TStichwort : IStichwort
{
```

(and still, there are missing a few references in the interface)

**My question now is:**

Is it good or bad practice, having such huge generic interfaces? If not, what would be a better pattern to realize this?
my API-controller will need all those references for filtering. So I got a lot of `Include(...).Include(...).Include(...).Where(...)`

Comment: Why not have the two contexts use the same entity classes? Then you can get rid of the interfaces, makes it a lot simpler.

Comment: @Maarten sorry, updated the question, they share **nearly** the same tables and properties. both have some individual tables with a few own references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: This is a primarily opinion based answer (but too long for a comment)

If I were you I would go a different way.

I would declare a data-service interface and a data class

```
interface IFooDataService
{
    Task<ICollection<Foo>> GetAllAsync();
}

class Foo
{
    // some properties
}
```

For each storage-point (Database, WebApi, whatever) I implement that interface and map the data from the storage to the `Foo` class.

And a wrapper class that will get the the data from multiple data-services

```
class CombinedFooDataService : IFooDataService
{
    private static readonly IFooDataService[] _services;

    public CombinedFooDataService( params IFooDataService[] services )
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<Foo>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var tasks = _services.Select( e => e.GetAllAsync() );
        var results = await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
        return results.SelectMany( e => e ).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I need to redesign my structure... great, this looks much more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

You must not use large interfaces, you must use small interfaces.
Interface Segregation Principle must be followed in code.